# Cant send contact form in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, twig, contact-form

I trying to send contact form in Symfony2, but i have the error:

```
Variable "form" does not exist in VputiMainBundle:Main:contact.html.twig at line 20
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function contactAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType());
    $formView = $form->createView();
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject($form->get('subject')->getData())
            ->setFrom($form->get('email')->getData())
            ->setTo('mail.com.deu')
            ->setBody(
                $this->renderView(
                    'VputiMainBundle:Main:contact.html.twig',
                    array(
                        'ip'      => $request->getClientIp(),
                        'name'    => $form->get('name')->getData(),
                        'message' => $form->get('body')->getData()
                    )
                )
            );
        if ($this->get('mailer')->send($message)) {
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('message_send', 'thanks!');
        } else {
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('send_error', 'error!');
        }
    }

    return $this->render('VputiMainBundle:Main:contact.html.twig', array('form' => $formView));
}
```

Where is my problem, what I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same template both for showing the form to send a contact request and the body of the mail. Notice the two `VputiMainBundle:Main:contact.html.twig`. If the form is valid it tries to render `contact.html.twig` which needs a `form` variable obviously.

Create a new template for the mail body which does not rely on the form view.